# Were ad clicks bounded by budget or natural causes?

Tags: time-series, censoring

So, I have a time series of historical data on some online ads. These ads are "cost per click" ads - we pay only when a user clicks on them. For the last 3 years, I know how much we spent on each ad, and how many clicks the ad got, for every single day.

What I don't know is what our budget was for that ad on that day. On some days, we may have maxed out our budget, and the ad stopped getting clicked because we didn't have any budget remaining. On other days, we didn't hit our budget limit, and the ad just didn't get clicked because not enough people wanted to click it.

Ultimately, I'm trying to forecast future ad clicks based on budget. In other words, if we set the budget for 750 dollars/day, we'll get 2000 clicks... But if we set it to 5000 dollars/day, we'd only get 2500 clicks, because there's not enough people that would click the ad to max out a 5k budget.

I have no idea what to use to tackle this... My only thought is that the standard deviation of clicks would likely be lower during periods when we were hitting the budget, because every day would have been the max of the budget...

Thoughts?

Comment: are you really saying you stored no other data, like eg how many impressions were made (to calculate CTR)

Comment: No, we have impressions, CTR, etc. Everything but budget. It's AdWords, and AdWords doesn't let you pull budget.

Comment: You are looking at a _possibly_ censored sample from above, with _unknown_ ceiling/censoring threshold...sounds tough.

Comment: Do you have any other information about how budgets were set historically?